# x3d inline example not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, x3d, x3dom

x3dom inline example is not loading properly on my internet explorer 11. It takes a long time. It's working fine on chrome, firefox, even edge. I have a project based on this example. I also found out that the following code is not working even if the model loads. IE couldn't find 'MA_Nose' material node inside the x3d file. How can I fix this. `if(document.getElementById('Deer__MA_Nose').getAttribute('diffuseColor')!= '1 0 0')`
Here is the link
[inline example html](https://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/models/inline/example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test your code in IE 11 browser.

I found that your example is showing this error.

[image]

This is the problematic line.

```
{while(inlScene.children.length){var childDomNode=inlScene.children[0];setNamespace(that._vf.nameSpaceName,childDomNode,that._vf.mapDEFToID);that._xmlNode.appendChild(childDomNode);}}}
```

This error is in **x3dom.js** file. So we cannot modify it.

I suggest you try to compile the file using [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/). It may help to fix ES6 code related issues by converting it to ES5 code.

If the issue persists then it can be possible that **inlScene.children.length** is not supported in the IE browser and you may need to use some polyfill to fix this issue.

further, you can also try to contact x3Dom support to get their opinion on this issue.